# Write a runCommands entry that will wrap selection, copy the selection then paste into a named existing file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on localizing a react web app where all strings are currently hard coded. To take the tedium out of manually wrapping each piece of text in a `{t('text to translate')}` and then copy and pasting into my english.json file, I'd like to write a `runComands` script and bind to a keyboard shortcut.

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```json
{ // create translation entry
  "key": "alt+shift+t",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
      "commands": [
          // copy current selection
          // wrap selection in "{t(" and ")}"
          // paste selection into english.json 
      ]
  }
}
```

Comment: you can try the extension I wrote: [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this keybinding:

```json
{
  "key": "alt+shift+t",
  "command": "runCommands",
  "args": {
      "commands": [

        // store selection in the clipboard
        // open '.......english.json'
        // insert a snippet that uses the clipboard text

        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",

        {
          "command": "vscode.open",
          "args": "file:///C:/Users/Mark/OneDrive/Test Bed/english.json"  // need the full path here
        },

        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "snippet": "{t(${CLIPBOARD})}",
          }
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

There is a bug in `runCommands` when using `editor.action.clipboardCopyAction`, so I substituted `editor.action.insertSnippet` instead.

---

There are ways to do this without using the clipboard, but that require using an extension.  If you want to see that let me know.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's a little out of order but I can fix it 
What is a good reference for the commands that are available in the keybindings file?

Comment: and yes I would like to see how this would be done in an extension.